# Rails 4 favicon in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I created a favicon for a rails app I've built a month ago.  Now I'm working on a new app without a particular favicon, yet every time I go to localhost:3000 the old favicon appears.  I know it really doesn't matter and it won't appear in production but it bugs me.  Can anyone explain why it keeps showing and how can I remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add which browsers you are using? I have noticed that different browsers cache more or less, so especially with Google Chrome, I had to hard reset all caches of the browser to get rid of cached images, css, ...

Comment: @mliebelt I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried to reset your cached images? See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?p=settings_clear_browsing_data&rd=1 for details

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple, the browser is being smart and caches the favicon as it associates it with the URL, i.e. `http://localhost:3000`.

To test it in Chrome, just open `http://localhost:3000` in an incognito window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and you will not see the favicon there.

To remove the favicon, simply *clear the browser cache*.

Comment: The old favicon appears when I open an incognito window.  I also cleared my cache to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in development on localhost:3000 because it got cached.if run your server on different port like 4000(rails s -p 4000) and access localhost:4000 then it won't show you the old favicon.